# bootstrap table: filter control not working

Tags: javascript, django, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

With my bootstrap table I want to use the extension [Filter Control](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#extensions/filter-control.html)

Server side I'm using django.

I include following css and js:

```
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.18.1/bootstrap-table.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.18.1/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.css">

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.18.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.18.1/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.js" ></script>
```

And here my html table:

```
<table
  id="table"
  data-toggle="table"
  data-pagination="true"
  data-pagination-h-align="left"
  data-pagination-detail-h-align="right"
  data-page-size="25"
  data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, all]"
  data-search="true"
  data-show-columns="true"
  data-filter-control="true"
  data-show-search-clear-button="true"
  data-show-refresh="true"
  data-url="../get_track_list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="datetime_start" data-formatter="DateFormatter" data-sortable="true" data-switchable="false" data-searchable="false">Date</th>
      <th data-field="name" data-formatter="ActivityLinkFormatter" data-switchable="false">Name</th>
      <th data-field="sport" data-formatter="SportSymbolFormatter" data-sortable="true" data-searchable="false" data-filter-control="select">Sport</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

My data-url is a json file from a django request.

The resulting table looks like this:
[image]

I don't have any errors in the browser console. I also see the the filter-control div was created but not the dropdown field?
[image]

What I'm doing wrong, so that the `data-filter-control="select"` field is not created?
The table is rendered without using any js functions, in my js file are just the custom `data-formatter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried run the input that you provided in `https://live.bootstrap-table.com/` and the filter controls works only after removing the `data-searchable="false"` (or setting it to `true`).

So you should remove the `data-searchable="false"` or set it to `true`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, filter-control was not working due to **data-height**. I removed data-height and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).